# Java Velruse equivalent for Open Identification (OpenId, Google, Facebook, Yahoo, ...)

Tags: java, openid, openid-selector

I've be looking for a while now but only found old or incomplete projects related to this purpose.

[Velruse](https://velruse.readthedocs.org) is Python library for identification thanks to OpenId, Google account, Facebook connect, etc .. and I didn't find the equivalent for Java but I guess it may exist I'm just not looking in the good direction!

If anyone has experienced this before could he share his knowledge on this.

---

What I've found:

[OpenID4Java](https://code.google.com/p/openid4java/) : Seems to be only for openID

[JOpenID](https://code.google.com/p/jopenid/wiki/JOpenId?tm=6) : Seems to be only for openId

[OpenId Selector](https://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) : Javascript client side implementation providing openID, could be coupled with one of the previous java library on the server side.

Comment: [Janrain](http://janrain.com/) looks like a company offering some services also around authentification.

I'm considering creating a Velruse4Java mapping if I don't find anything in pure java ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Velruse as a service](http://velruse.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#as-a-service), you don't need to know python. You only need to connect and velruse does the magic for you :)

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I'm using Play! Authenticate right now but cause I switched to this framework. I think the answer is great anyway